# I have service running in VPS and i would like to get that entire traffic to my remote machine. What are the ways to get that whole traffic?

Tags: vpn, vps

I have a Tor relay running in VPS and i would like to get that entire traffic to my remote system. What are the ways to get that whole traffic?

One option would be VPN but i am getting all traffic encrypted in the VPN tunnel.
Need to see exact traffic at my remote machine for analysis.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking for? You want to send the internet traffic of your local device to the relay?

Comment: No, i need to get VPS (remotely run relay) traffic to my local machine!

Comment: It sounds like you want to analyze relay traffic, so please don't do this, it may harm real people and may get your relay removed from the network.